# How Bloomberg calculates discount rates for zero rate curves?

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap, bloomberg, bootstrapping, discounting

I would like to ask about discount rates calculation algorithm by Bloomberg terminal.[image: Zero Curve from Bloomberg Terminal]

In the image above is possible to notice the discount rate for each term. The short end, instruments from 1 DY up to 18 MO, is composed by zero coupon swaps. The long end, instruments from 2 YR up to 20 YR, is composed by swaps compounded daily with quartly coupon payments.

We can see the 2 YR instrument description below:
[image: 2 YR Instrument Description]

I was able to calculate the discount rate for the short end by using the following formula:

[image]

We can easily check that above formula works for every term of the short end, e. g., for 3 MO term (curve date 10mar22), we have that: market rate is 5.905 and period is 92 days (14jun22 minus 14mar22).

[image]

Since the long term instruments has coupon payments, the formula above is not apropriate.

**1. How can I replicate the discount for long end terms?**

Comment: Bloomberg help page for the ICVS function includes a paper named "Building the Bloomberg Interest Rate Curve – Definitions and Methodology." Did you check it?

Comment: I have the same problem here, I asked the Help Desk and they Forwarded me to the Building the Bloomberg Interest Rate Curve: Definitions and Methodology paper, but in fact they dont explain anitying about this.

Short tenors (less than a year) are ok using without using compounding + taking in account the day count of the market data (ACT/360 for the S42 USD OIS)